# Will PS5 play DVD / Blu-ray at 1.5x speed with audio?

Tags: ps5

My PS3 does a neat trick that my other DVD players can't: it can play back DVD or Blu-ray discs at 1.5x speed *with* (sped up) audio. [This thread at Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/boutiquebluray/comments/jig1nf/region_free_player_with_15_speed_option/) seems to imply the PS4 has the same feature.

What about the PS5? Would an owner confirm or deny, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only tried this with a Blu-ray movie but I can confirm that the PS5 lets you watch it in 1.5x speed. You have to press the R2 trigger to speed up the movie, and the next step-up is 10x speed.

Comment: @webniraj, _with_ audio, are you sure?

Comment: @MarkKnutsen Yes, if you watch on 1.5x speed, it will play with sped up audio on both Blu-Ray and DVD (I tried it with both). All other fast forward or backward options play without audio.

Comment: Yep, 1.5x with audio.